# In MVC 5 - How to compare 2 boolean values and set it as a third booelan in View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have

View

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.IsPersistable})
```

Model

```
public class MyModel()
{
  public bool IsPersistable{ get; set; }
  public bool StoreAsIndiv {get;set;}
  public bool StoreAsOrg {get;set;}
}
```

I have 2 check boxes in the view mapping to `StoreAsIndiv` and `StoreAsOrg`.   If either of them are selected I wanted to assign true to `IsPersistable` which is a hidden field.

How to accomplish this?

**EDIT/Update:** I want to avoid any Javascript if possible

Comment: You do this with JavaScript if the user has altered the original page value.

Comment: Is there a way with no usage of Javascript?

Comment: The key question you need to answer is: Has the user altered the original values? If yes, you must use client-side code.

Comment: The user can change the original values...but I just need the `IsPersistable` to be set on the submit action I have on this form

Comment: are you trying to set the value in runtime?

Comment: If the user can alter the values but not affect `IsPersistable` then `@{ Model.IsPersistable = Model.StoreAsIndiv || Model.StoreAsOrg; }`

Comment: `@Html.HiddenFor(@{ Model.IsPersistable = Model.StoreAsIndiv || Model.StoreAsOrg; }) `
Is this your suggestion?

Comment: Why do you even need that hidden input in the view. Just set its value in the POST method based on the values of `StoreAsIndiv` and `StoreAsOrg` (which you need to do anyway)

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
$(function(){
    var isPersistableEle = $("#IsPersistable");
    var storeAsIndivEle = $("#StoreAsIndiv");
    var storeAsOrgEle = $("#StoreAsOrg");

    function checkUncheckIsPersistable(){
        if(storeAsIndivEle.is(':checked') 
           && storeAsOrgEle.is(':checked')){
            isPersistableEle.prop('checked', true); 
        } else {
            isPersistableEle.prop('checked', false); 
        }
    }

    storeAsIndivEle.on("change", function(){
        checkUncheckIsPersistable();
    });

    storeAsOrgEle.on("change", function(){
        checkUncheckIsPersistable();
    })  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you say that the value of `IsPersistable`  will only be set at view render then you can try something like that

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.IsPersistable, new { Value = Model.StoreAsIndiv || Model.StoreAsOrg })
```

or if you want to change the value in model @Jasen's answer is best

Answer (score 1):

If the user can alter the values but not affect IsPersistable then

```
@model MyModel
@{
    Model.IsPersistable = Model.StoreAsIndiv || Model.StoreAsOrg;
}

@Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.IsPersistable)
```

The `HiddenFor()` will pickup the value you set earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your model to this:

```
public class MyModel()
{
  public bool IsPersistable{ get { return StorageAsIndiv || StorageAsOrg; }
  public bool StoreAsIndiv {get;set;}
  public bool StoreAsOrg {get;set;}
}
```

If IsPersistable is a field you will use on the controller, you don't need javascript. If you are planning to manipulate the dom based on it's value, you will have to use some as @Christos suggested above.